# Simple calculations on vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am using VB.NET, i am new to VB.NET and i tried to make simple form with calculations such as addition, subtraction and multiplications and divisions by using text boxes and buttons.
For my project i need to calculate three vales by using three formulas. The three vales then need to be multiplied in order to get the final value.

Here are the formulas used:

Availability = (Operating time - downtime)/Operating time x 100

Performance efficiency = (Theoretical Cycle time x Processed amount)/ Operating time x 100

Rate of Quality = (Processed amount - defect amount)/ processed amount x 100

Overall Equipment Effectiveness = Availability x Performance efficiency x Rate of Quality

I managed to get the values for the 3 formulas, however whenever i tried to get the final value (Overall Equipment Effectiveness = Availability x Performance efficiency x Rate of Quality) the value i get is still 0, and all the other values i calculated turn to 0 as well. I will post my code below, any help is much appreciated. Thank you for your time and patience :)

```
Public Class OEE

Private Sub OEE_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub Label9_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox9_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim number1 As Integer
    Dim number2 As Integer
    Dim answer1 As Decimal
    Dim sum1 As Integer
    Dim sum2 As Integer

    number1 = TextBox5.Text
    number2 = TextBox6.Text
    sum1 = number1 - number2
    sum2 = number1 * 100
    answer1 = sum1 / sum2
    TextBox4.Text = answer1
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim number3 As Integer
    Dim number4 As Integer
    Dim number5 As Integer
    Dim answer2 As Decimal
    Dim sum3 As Integer
    Dim sum4 As Integer

    number3 = TextBox2.Text
    number4 = TextBox11.Text
    number5 = TextBox5.Text
    sum3 = number3 * number5
    sum4 = number4 * 100
    answer2 = sum3 / sum4
    TextBox1.Text = answer2
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim number6 As Integer
    Dim number7 As Integer
    Dim answer3 As Decimal
    Dim sum5 As Integer
    Dim sum6 As Integer

    number6 = TextBox11.Text
    number7 = TextBox8.Text
    sum5 = number6 - number7
    sum6 = number6 * 100
    answer3 = sum5 / sum6
    TextBox7.Text = answer3

End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Dim answer1 As Decimal
    Dim answer2 As Decimal
    Dim answer3 As Decimal
    Dim total As Decimal

    TextBox4.Text = answer1
    TextBox1.Text = answer2
    TextBox7.Text = answer3
    total = answer1 * answer2 * answer3

    TextBox10.Text = total

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox10_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox10.TextChanged

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You're allowed to rename controls. That would make it a lot easier to understand your code, rather than trying to fathom out what `TextBox7` is. (I'd also suggest better naming of your variables too - rather than `answer1`, `answer2`, etc, why not have `availability`, `performanceEfficiency`, etc?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start with:

In your last code routine, your are equaling the textboxes to the decimals, you should equal the decimals to the textboxes?

```
answer1 = TextBox4.Text 
answer2 = TextBox1.Text
answer3 = TextBox7.Text

total = answer1 * answer2 * answer3
```

Comment: Great. Welcome to coding... :-)